# Jquery chosen set selected values from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery chosen and I want to set selected values from javascript

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedUserRole = document.getElementById('SelectedUserRole').value;
  var str_array = selectedUserRole.split(',');

  for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    // Trim the excess whitespace.
    str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    // Add additional code here, such as:

    $("UserRole").prop('selectedValue', str_array[i]); // Here not working
  }
});
```

**Html:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("UserRole", null, new { id = "UserRole", @class = "chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Lütfen Rol Seçiniz", @style = "width: 250px;" })
```

str_array has values below

[5, 1, 7]

I want to **set 5 value selected, 1 value selected 7 value selected**

When I tried below

```
$("UserRole").prop('selectedValue', str_array[i]);
```

it is not working for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to trigger the `chosen:updated` event after setting the `select` value

```
$("#UserRole").val(str_array[i]).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

---

To select multiple values

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectedUserRole = document.getElementById('SelectedUserRole').value;

    var str_array = selectedUserRole.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
        str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    }

    $("#UserRole").val(str_array).trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xuc68kv/)

Comment: thanks for help it works however selected value is always last index how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 6):

As of now this way is supported to update multiple values:

```
$("#UserRole").val(str_array).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

You missed '#'

```
$("#UserRole").prop('selectedValue', str_array[i]);
```

Comment: it works but it always set last index how can i solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$("UserRole").prop('selectedValue', str_array[i]);
```

It should be

```
$("#UserRole").prop('selectedValue', str_array[i]); // include '#' id selector here
```

Comment: no warnings no error however not selecting anything

Comment: @byto...you missed `#` in jQuery selector just correct it.